# Ordering an NSArray with NSDictionaries with objects

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

I have an array of dictionaries that contains objects like in the image below:

[image]

The problem I have is that I need to order the array by dates, for example in the first object I have a dueDate that is greater than the dueDate of the second object, then I have to swap them, so in other word I need to order the dictionaries inside the array based on the dueDate in ascending order, anyone have ideas?, I have tried with NSpredicate, with sortDescriptors but it isnt working, here is my sortDescriptors code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dueDate" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"overDueDate" ascending:YES];
NSArray *descriptors = @[descriptor, descriptor2];
tasksResultArray = [tasksResultArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easier:

```
arrayOfDictionaries = [arrayOfDictionaries sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

    // The logic for comparing dates, and returning the corresponding result

    NSDate *date1 = (NSDate *) [(NSDictionary *)obj1 objectForKey:@"dueDate"];
    NSDate *date2 = (NSDate *) [(NSDictionary *)obj2 objectForKey:@"dueDate"];

    return [date1 compare:date2];
}];
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't work, the date variables are nil, also, there are some dictionaries where the pendingTasks array have more than 1 element, any ideas?

Comment: Try to figure out how to correctly extract the dates from the dictionary, maybe you need to do some parsing on that. I think once you have the dates available, it should work fine.